# How to get the directory of the windows fonts?

Tags: java, windows, directory

I want to create a function that retrieves the windows \ system \ fonts directory.
It must not be hard-coded.

Iv'e heard there is somthing like :

```
%WINDIR%/fonts
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `sun.font.FontManager`:

```
System.out.println( FontManager.getFontPath( true ) );
```

Comment: My Java version string says "1.8.0_51", and the only members my "sun.font.FontManager" has are class, LOGICAL_FALLBACK, NO_FALLBACK, PHYSICAL_FALLBACK - but I found "sun.font.SunFontManager" which has getPlatformFontPath(boolean) and other interesting methods. There is also "sun.font.FontManager fm = sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance();", which has yet different methods (and few).

Comment: Interesting but note that class may be renamed or removed in the future (as was the case here) ....:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [System.getEnv(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) command

Something like

```
String path = System.getEnv("WINDIR");
File fontDirectory = new File(path, "Fonts");
```

Answer (score 1):

In java 1.7, FontManager has been discontinued.
Hence, if you are using Java 1.7, you can use the following:-

`String systemRoot = System.getenv().get("SystemRoot");`